# How do I get a list of EC2 instances for a given role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm launching an EC2 instance with an IAM role. Assuming that I don't store the instance ID when I launch it, how can I use the Amazon API to find which instance I assigned the role to?

I tried using DescribeInstances, but that doesn't seem to have a property for the role.

Comment: it doesn't appear to be available as a filter, but DescribeInstances *will* return role information, so if you run it across all your instances, you can filter it on your side.

Comment: Aha, I see, I was looking for the word 'role', but the element is named 'iamInstanceProfile'.

Comment: If you want to re-submit as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I'll do that- but it might be a bit, I want to make a working example.

Comment: And actually now that I know what to look for, it is a filter option available in DescribeInstances: iam-instance-profile.arn

Comment: oh, it'll be easier for you to answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looking for 'roles', look for 'iamInstanceProfile' elements when using the DescribeInstances API call. You can either get all instance profiles and then filter the results by this value, or you can specify it as a search filter using the 'iam-instance-profile.arn' element, with a wildcard for everything but the role name, like this: '*/RoleName'